# How to get value from column that is in a N-N relationship table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im having a problem. I have two tables, places and cuisines, and cuisine_place and in that table I have a column called default (that shows if that cuisine is the default cuisine for that place). But Im having the problem that Im not able to access to that column.

How can I do?

What I want to do is have them in this answer:

```
$places = Place::all()->with('cuisines')->withPivot('default');
```

Something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a many to many relationship between **places** and **cuisines**.  That relationship would be defined in the following fashion in your models:

```
public function cuisines(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Cuisine', 'cuisine_place');

}
```

The above would be a function in your **Place** class that references its relationship to the **cuisines** table.  By default, Eloquent will pick up the foreign keys in the **cuisine_place** table (in your case they would probably be called *cuisine_id* and *place_id*).  If you want to pick up additional columns from that table on calls to the above relationship function, you can use the `withPivot` function:

```
public function cuisines(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Cuisine', 'cuisine_place')->withPivot('default');

}
```

Now, on calls to the `cuisines()` method in your **Place** class, you'll receive the *default* column in the object associated with that table.

Comment: I update the question, look if u undersant what I mean, I dont know if its possible

Comment: @user2540080 You don't call `withPivot()` in your controller, you call it in your model.  All you need in your controller is `Place::all()->with('cuisines');`

Answer (score 0):

Open documentation for [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

And read about **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**

You didn't provide your models code so it's difficult to help you with the exact solution